# Meteor variable in template instead of function

Tags: function, templates, variables, meteor, spacebars

Is there a way in Meteor spacebars to store a template function return value? 
I'll explain better.

Suppose, for instance, I need to know if an event is started.
On client.js I will have:

```
Template.event.isEventStarted = function(eventId) {
    var event = Events.findOne({_id: eventId});
    return Events.isStarted(event);
}
```

Suppose now I need to access "isEventStarted" from the "event" template many times. I will need also to access it from subtemplates. The query is obviously executed everytime "isEventStarted" is called, so does the function "isStarted". They execute client side, but I could potentially have many events templates with many subtemplates.

Answer (score 1):

That's basically what `UI.emboxValue` is designed for. Try doing this:

```
Template.event.isEventStarted = function (eventId) {
  return UI.namedEmboxValue(eventId, function () {
     /* ... */
  }, EJSON.equals);
};
```

This way you can be sure the query will only be recomputed when the corresponding data changes.

Comment: It seems I cannot access collections inside emboxValue function. So I tried to move my collections files under "lib" folders and I could use "Events" collection in the function. But "eventId" keeps to be "undefined". I pass event id from template with {{#if isEventStarted _id}}.